# Exception While Running SpringWS JUnit Test : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-ws, spring-test

> I am getting an exception when I try to run the Spring Web Service JUnit Test Using the Spring WebService ServerSide Integration Test using MockWebServiceClient. When I run the WebService (Not Test), it is running fine but when I run the Junit Test, I'm getting many exceptions.

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext**

and

**Error creating bean with name 'spring_WS_ServletConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource';**

Can anybody please tell me what's going on these codes?

---

**Spring_WS_ServletConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.springws.endpoint", "com.mybatis.", "com.mapstruct" })
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml" })
public class Spring_WS_ServletConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean("StudentServiceWsdl")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition orders() throws SQLException {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        definition.setPortTypeName("StudentService_SpringWS_PortType");
        definition.setLocationUri("http://localhost:8080/MvnSpringMcc/StudentService_SpringWS/");
        definition.setTargetNamespace("com.springws.student/LearnSpringWs");
        definition.setServiceName("SpringWSService");
        definition.setSchema(studentsSchema());

        return definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema studentsSchema() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/wsdl/StudentTask.xsd");
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("/Schema_Wsdl/StudentTask.xsd"));
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor validator = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        validator.setValidateRequest(true);
        validator.setValidateResponse(true);
        validator.setSchema(new ClassPathResource("/Schema_Wsdl/StudentTask.xsd"));
    }
}
```

---

**CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Spring_WS_ServletConfig.class })
public class CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

    @Before
    public void createClient() {
        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void customerEndpoint() throws Exception {
        Resource requestPayLoad = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:xmlTestFiles/RequestPayLoad.xml");
        Resource responsePayLoad = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:xmlTestFiles/ResponsePayLoad.xml");

        mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayLoad)).andExpect(payload(responsePayLoad));
    }
}
```

---

**RequestPayLoad.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:lear="com.springws.student/LearnSpringWs" xmlns:stud="com.springws.student/StudentSchema">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <lear:GetCourseRequest>
            <lear:Course>
                <stud:courseID>100</stud:courseID>
            </lear:Course>
        </lear:GetCourseRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

```
customerEndpoint(com.springws.test.CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.009 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spring_WS_ServletConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseMapper' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentMapper' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'courseMapper' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'studentMapper' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sqlSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sqlSessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spring_WS_ServletConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1316)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 74 more


Results :

Tests in error: 
  customerEndpoint(com.springws.test.CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Answer (score 0):

As it clearly stated in Exception message - no bean of DataSource class was found within Application Context of the test run. You can either

1) remove injection of DataSource into Spring_WS_ServletConfig since it seems to be not used in that class

2) provide DataSource bean (real or mock, depending on your needs), for example like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { Spring_WS_ServletConfig.class, CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest.class })
@Configuration // << in order to use this class as "bean provider"
public class CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("test.database.driver"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("test.database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("test.database.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("test.database.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

// or it can be just mocked using Mockito or similar framework

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
         return Mockito.mock(DataSource.class)
    }
// ...

}
```

Comment: I added the DataSource Manually and it's working fine with the Database. However now, I'm getting another Exception: No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage

Comment: Same issue here, I guess. No controller that is mapped to your endpoint is found in application context.

Comment: I have fixed the issue; visit my another  link of the StackOverflow Post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758638/solved-springws-junit-test-exception-no-endpoint-can-be-found-for-request-saa