# SpringWS Junit Test Exception: No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws, spring-test

> I am getting an exception when I try to run the Spring Web Service JUnit Test Using the Spring WebService ServerSide Integration Test using MockWebServiceClient. When I run the WebService Junit Test, I'm getting an exception:

***No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessagehttp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]***

---

**Spring_WS_ServletConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWs
@EnableTransactionManagement
// @ComponentScan({ "com.springws.endpoint", "com.mybatis.", "com.mapstruct" })
// @ImportResource({ "classpath:/SpringConfig/spring-database-config.xml" })
public class Spring_WS_ServletConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean("StudentServiceWsdl")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition orders() throws SQLException {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        definition.setPortTypeName("StudentService_SpringWS_PortType");
        definition.setLocationUri("http://localhost:8080/MvnSpringMcc/StudentService_SpringWS/");
        definition.setTargetNamespace("com.springws.student/LearnSpringWs");
        definition.setServiceName("SpringWSService");
        // definition.setWsdl(new
        // ClassPathResource("/wsdl/StudentService.wsdl"));
        definition.setSchema(studentsSchema());

        return definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema studentsSchema() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/wsdl/StudentTask.xsd");
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("/Schema_Wsdl/StudentTask.xsd"));
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        PayloadValidatingInterceptor validator = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
        validator.setValidateRequest(true);
        validator.setValidateResponse(true);
        validator.setSchema(new ClassPathResource("/Schema_Wsdl/StudentTask.xsd"));
    }
}
```

---

**TestConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.springws.test", "com.mybatis.mapper.vo", "com.mybatis.service", "com.mapstruct.mapper",
        "com.springws.endpoint", "com.mybatis.mapper" })
//@Import(Spring_WS_ServletConfig.class)
@ImportResource({ "classpath:testResources/spring-ws-test-database-config.xml" })
public class TestConfig {
}
```

---

**CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class, Spring_WS_ServletConfig.class })
public class CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private MockWebServiceClient mockClient;

    @Before
    public void createClient() {
        mockClient = MockWebServiceClient.createClient(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void courseEndpoint() throws Exception {
        Resource requestPayLoad = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:xmlTestFiles/RequestPayLoad.xml");
        Resource responsePayLoad = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:xmlTestFiles/ResponsePayLoad.xml");

        mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayLoad)).andExpect(payload(responsePayLoad));
    }
}
```

**RequestPayLoad.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:lear="com.springws.student/LearnSpringWs" xmlns:stud="com.springws.student/StudentSchema">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <lear:GetCourseRequest>
            <lear:Course>
                <stud:courseID>100</stud:courseID>
            </lear:Course>
        </lear:GetCourseRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

**Exception**

```
CourseServiceEndpoint(com.springws.endpoint.CourseServiceEndpoint)  Time elapsed: 0.219 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]
    at org.springframework.ws.test.support.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
    at org.springframework.ws.test.server.MockWebServiceClient.sendRequest(MockWebServiceClient.java:184)
    at com.springws.serverside.test.CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest.courseEndpoint(CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Failed tests:   CourseServiceEndpoint(com.springws.serverside.test.CourseServiceEndPointServerSideIntegrationTest): No endpoint can be found for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]
```

Comment: You can try something different on your integration test. Seems to me that use MockServiceClient is not anymore the best way to make the integration test on Soap Web Service. See this example: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-producing-web-service/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/ApplicationIntegrationTests.java

Comment: @Dherik, this page you provide is not found.

Answer (score 3):

The better way to solve this problem is to change for proper methods in `RequestCreators`
and `ResponseMatchers` for SOAP one.

```
import static org.springframework.ws.test.server.RequestCreators.withSoapEnvelope;
import static org.springframework.ws.test.server.ResponseMatchers.soapEnvelope;
```

Changes need to be done in our test method.

Before:

`mockClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayLoad)).andExpect(payload(responsePayLoad));`

After:

```
mockClient.sendRequest(withSoapEnvelope(requestPayLoad)).andExpect(soapEnvelope(responsePayLoad));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to solve the problem: Just provide the Soap Payload Information in the `MockWebServiceClient.sendRequest`'s `withPayload()` & `andExpect(payload())` methods.

**RequestPayLoad.xml**

```
<lear:GetCourseRequest xmlns:lear="com.springws.student/LearnSpringWs"
    xmlns:stud="com.springws.student/StudentSchema">
    <lear:Course>
        <stud:courseID>100</stud:courseID>
    </lear:Course>
</lear:GetCourseRequest>
```

**ResponsePayLoad.xml**

```
<ns3:GetCourseResponse xmlns:ns2="com.springws.student/StudentSchema"
    xmlns:ns3="com.springws.student/LearnSpringWs">
    <ns3:Course>
        <ns2:courseID>100</ns2:courseID>
        <ns2:courseName>Physics</ns2:courseName>
        <ns2:courseCategory>Physics</ns2:courseCategory>
        <ns2:credit>3.0</ns2:credit>
    </ns3:Course>
</ns3:GetCourseResponse>
```